# Prevent creation of ~ files

Tags: auto-save

Emacs keeps pooping out random `.extension~` files that are messing up my program. How do I prevent creation of these files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting this in your configuration

`(setq make-backup-files nil)`

A more elaborate answer and explanation of the underlying feature

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151945/how-do-i-control-how-emacs-makes-backup-files